# DB2 - Can I recreate a foreign key constraint in a table with data?

Tags: sql, db2, constraints

I'm having the following problem with DB2:
I need to change a column name (column "A"), but the thing is that column A has a PK constraint and a FK constraint. So I need to drop this constraints first, change the column name and then create the constraints again. But I remember a Professor told me once that you can't create a foreign key in a column which already has values. Is that true?

This is my script:

```
ALTER TABLE TARGET_TABLE 
    DROP PRIMARY KEY PK_A CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE TARGET_TABLE 
    RENAME COLUMN A TO B;

alter table TARGET_TABLE 
add CONSTRAINT PK_B PRIMARY KEY( B);

alter table TARGET_TABLE add CONSTRAINT FK_B FOREIGN KEY( B) REFERENCES OTHER_TABLE(C);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a foreign key on a column which already has values. The only restriction is that the values must be be valid for the FK you are defining.

If not you will get an error such as

```
SQL0667N  The FOREIGN KEY "I..." cannot be created because the table contains 
rows with foreign key values that cannot be found in the parent key of the 
parent table.  SQLSTATE=23520
```